# I want to count records from a database where the columns have the same value

Tags: mysql

I have t table which contains views from books:

```
ID    UserID    TIME            BookID
1     2         (timedate)      1
1     3         (timedate)      1
1     54        (timedate)      1
1     4        (timedate)       2
1     5        (timedate)       2
much more ....
```

I been trying to get a query which counts the number of views of the books and list them from highest to lowest.

I want to do this so I can display 5 books with the highs amount of views in the past month.

Non of the given are working!

Im putting it through a while loop if that helps.

```
$gethotbookq = mysqli_query($con,"select BookID, count(*) as views
from `BOOKS_views`
where `TIME` >= '2014-05-01 00:00:00' and `TIME` < '2014-06-01 00:00:00'
group by BookID
order by views desc
limit 5") or die();

while($gethotbook = mysql_fetch_array($gethotbookq))
{
$bookid = $gethotbook['BookID'];

}
```

Comment: sorry I have lost some of the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select bookID, count(*) as views
from books
where `time` >= '2014-04-01' and `time` < '2014-05-01'
group by bookID
order by views desc
limit 5
```

Comment: didn't work pal, I've updated the question with my code

Comment: What does *didn't work* mean exactly? Did you get an error? Did you get unexpected results? How does your dates look like? What data type are they?

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Are the UserIDs the views?

this may help with counting the number of times a book shows  up in the book ID. As long as there are not a lot of the smae user looking at the same book then the views should be pretty accruate.

[SQL: How to get the count of each distinct value in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053902/sql-how-to-get-the-count-of-each-distinct-value-in-a-column)

following that you should have a list of all the booksIDs and a count of views and could sort the views highest to lowest.