# SQL command to check Domain Emails

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with a list of emails. How do I retrieve the count value and the unique domain names from the table?

For example,

```
EmailTable
abc@yahoo.com
abc1@yahoo.com
abc@hotmail.com
abc23@hotmail.com
def@gmail.com
```

The above  should ideally return something as follows:

```
count EmailDomain
2     yahoo.com
2     hotmail.com
1     gmail.com
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: How to get the count of each distinct value in a column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053902/sql-how-to-get-the-count-of-each-distinct-value-in-a-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with basic string manipulations and aggregation:

```
select substr(e.email, instr(email, '@') + 1) as domain, count(*)
from emails e
group by substr(e.email, instr(email, '@') + 1);
```

Comment: You missed the closing parenthesis. But I think this is what you want to write `select substr(e.email, instr(email, '@') + 1) as domain, count(*) from emails e group by domain;`