# SQL: Number of Comments left by single commenter

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying to get the number of comments left by each commenter (subscriber) and order from highest to least.

For Starters this was the first link I went to :

[SQL: How to get the count of each distinct value in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053902/sql-how-to-get-the-count-of-each-distinct-value-in-a-column)

Similar problem, except in my first column the values may repeat. Mine looks something like this.

```
email   | comment
--------------------
foo@bar | blah..
bar@bar | blah..
zob@bar | blah..
foo@bar | blah..
foo@bar | blah..
bar@bar | blah..
```

and essentially all I need to do is get an output like this

```
-foo@bar (3)
-bar@bar (2)
-zob@bar (1)
```

I know this may be very trivial, I just don't use SQL queries that often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
  email, count(*)
from
  mytable
group by email
order by count(*) desc
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/647e1/1)

Comment: @Brandon10x, glad to be of help.  Welcome to SO. :)