# Get Count of different values in comma separated row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string-aggregation

A table Jobs which have 2 column JobId, City when we save job a job location may be multiple city like below

```
-----------------------------
JobId               City
-------------------------------
1                   New York
2                   New York , Ohio , Virginia
3                   New York , Virginia
```

how i count jobid in perticular city like i want count of jobid in New York city
i want result like

New York  3
Ohio      1
Virginia  2

Comment: Have you tried this on your own? It's a typical scenario.

Comment: i tied it by group by cityname it give city name 3 time in case of new york and count 3

Comment: Include the query you tried in your question.

Comment: Select city,Count(*) from Table group by city; but it's not useful for me @EternalHour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(all_city, ',', num), ',', -1) AS one_city,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(city separator ',') AS all_city,
    LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(citySEPARATOR ',')) - LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(citySEPARATOR ','), ',', '')) + 1 AS count_city
  FROM table_name
) t
JOIN numbers n
ON n.num <= t.count_city
GROUP BY one_city
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

for getting count of comma separated distinct value run above query but getting correct resulr you should use one more table `**numbers**` which have only one column num integer type  and insert some values. 
if you getting error during GROUP_CONCAT(city separator ',') AS all_city in this condition set a global variable  " SET group_concat_max_len = 18446744073709547520; "

Comment: This doesn't work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nSjT5XVcskixjxiSbGczTg/0

Answer (score 3):

Your database is poorly designed and you are going to have a lot of trouble down the line.
Using the current structure you can get the count using the `find_in_set` function but that you should avoid .

Your table is as

```
create table test
(jobid int ,city varchar(100));

insert into test values 
(1,'New York'),
(2,'New York, Ohio,Virginia'),
(3,'New York,Virginia');
```

Now to get the count you can use the following

```
select 
count(*) as tot from test
where 
find_in_set('Virginia',city) > 0;
```

As I mentioned this is a poor db design the ideal would be as

- first a job table with job details
- a location table containing all the locations
- and finally a table linking a job and a location

So it would look like

```
create table jobs (jobid int, name varchar(100));

insert into jobs values
(1,'PHP'),(2,'Mysql'),(3,'Oracle');

create table locations (id int, name varchar(100));
insert into locations values (1,'New York'),(2,'Ohio'),(3,'Virginia');

create table job_locations (id int, jobid int, location_id int);

insert into job_locations values
(1,1,1),(2,2,1),(3,2,2),(4,2,3),(5,3,1),(6,3,3);
```

Now getting the count and many more operations will be fairly easy

```
select
count(j.jobid) as  tot
from jobs j 
join job_locations jl on jl.jobid = j.jobid
join locations l on l.id = jl.location_id
where
l.name = 'Virginia'
```

For counting all the jobs per city and using the above schema it would very simple

```
select
l.name,
count(j.jobid) as  tot
from jobs j 
join job_locations jl on jl.jobid = j.jobid
join locations l on l.id = jl.location_id
group by l.name
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10d51/2)**

Comment: I want count of id for all city at a time 
like
New York 3
Virginia 2
Ohio     1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS jobs 
  FROM Jobs
 WHERE FIELD_IN_SET('New York') > 0
;
```

You should read about database normalization though. Having a comma separated list of values in a database table always has a 'smell', e.g. you can only check for a specific city name here and can't easily create a list of job counts for all cities referred to in the job table in one go ...

See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization for a start ...

Answer (score 0):

Make `JobId` and `City` column as joined primary key. This will make your life easier. Do not insert multiple cities separated by commas.

```
-------------------------------------------------
JobId               City         // Other columns
-------------------------------------------------
1                   New York
2                   New York
2                   Ohio
2                   Virginia
3                   New York
3                   Virginia
```

Now you make the query will be something like this

```
select city, count(jobid) FROM TABLE GROUP BY city  // Result will be New York 3, Ohio 1 and Virginia 2
```

Comment: according to your suggestion i am able to count only one city count but i want all city job count at a time

Comment: SELECT COUNT(jobid), city FROM TABLE GROUP BY city

Comment: I want count of id corresponding to all city

Comment: You want the result 4 (it counts repeating cites just one time) **OR** result 6 (it does NOT count repeating cities just one time) ... So what result you want ??

Comment: i want result like 
new york 3
virginia 2
Ohio     1

Comment: @Junaid you are twice selecting city

Answer (score 0):

Design your table as mentioned below. Each city name and Job Id in each row.

```
Job ID      City Name
1           New York
2           New York
1           Seattle
```

Then use the query as mentioned in the below link.

[SQL: How to get the count of each distinct value in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053902/sql-how-to-get-the-count-of-each-distinct-value-in-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query,

```
 SELECT COUNT(jobid), city FROM TABLE where city like '%newyork%';
```