# Count for separated by special symbol String in each row without using any other table or Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to get count of each value separated by ## without 
 using Any table or stored procedure . i have to get count for each value repeated by 
 special symbol as per the given schema. I have tried alot but i want to make this    result set without helping any reference table or stored procedure or temporary table.

```
Schema  is like this :-

CREATE TABLE USER_TABLE (
      id INT,
      name VARCHAR(20));


INSERT INTO USER_TABLE VALUES
(1, 'A##B##C'),
(2, 'B##C'),
(3,'A'),
(4,'B##C');
```

**Expected output is Like :-**

```
   Name  COUNT
     A     2
     B     3
     C     3
```

Comment: Normalize the table thats a bad db design.

Comment: Abhik, actally i am saving location multiple so i have to use this

Comment: No this is not correct way see my answer from yesterday with the normalization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165243/count-of-job-for-a-city-if-job-posted-for-multiple-city-at-a-time/27165603#27165603

Answer (score 0):

Try these query, may help you:

```
      Select GROUP_CONCAT((name) SEPARATOR '#') as name, count(name) as count FROM your_table
```