# MySQL innerjoin on an array field

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables

[series]

```
--------------
ID | ART
--------------
1  | sculptor      
2  | painter
3  | writer
-----------
```

[artists]

```
--------------
NAME | ART_IDs
--------------
john | 1
jack | 1,2
jill | 2,1
jeff | 3,1
```

which I want to join like this:

```
SELECT se.art, ar.name as artist
FROM series AS se
JOIN artists AS ar ON FIND_IN_SET(se.id , ar.art_ids) > 0
```

What I get is only the first values:

[result]

```
-------------------
ART      | ARTISTS
-------------------
sculptor | john
sculptor | jack
painter  | jill
writer   | jeff
```

Instead of:

[result]

```
----------------------------
ART               | ARTISTS
----------------------------
sculptor          | john
sculptor,painter  | jack
painter,sculptor  | jill
writer,sculptor   | jeff
```

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad database design. Think about normalization of your tables

Comment: Seriously consider Jens's comment above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Join two tables with comma separated values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101550/mysql-join-two-tables-with-comma-separated-values)

Comment: Go through 

http://stackoverflow.com/q/27165243/3725409

Comment: Or perhaps this is an even better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923471/mysql-join-comma-separated-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(se.art ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(se.id , ar.art_ids)) as art, ar.name as artist
FROM series AS se
JOIN artists AS ar ON FIND_IN_SET(se.id , ar.art_ids) > 0
GROUP BY ar.name
```

If you want to concat column in each group, `GROUP_CONCAT` can help you.

Check [**demo**](http://rextester.com/MPCQ2542) in Rextester.

Comment: its result is like this   
sculptor,sculptor,sculptor  | john  only with 1 row rest ommited

Comment: @FaiqAhmad Check demo.

Comment: here is my actual query  where table size have two fields 1-id 2-name  where my table products have id and size               "SELECT group_concat(size.name ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`eshop_trans`.`products`.`size`, `eshop_trans`.`size`.`id`)) as size,`products`.`id` FROM `eshop_trans`.`products` join `eshop_trans`.`size` on FIND_IN_SET(`eshop_trans`.`products`.`size`, `eshop_trans`.`size`.`id`)>0 group by `size`.name "