# fetch data from mysql database on the basis of leave types such as Exam, Unpaid, Annual

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

> This is my Database table

:
[image]

> This is my front end where i want display data:

[image]

What I need is employee leaves record on the basic of leave types and half day full day. from left to right employee name then annual count on the basis of half day = 1 in db and leave type = annual so on and in the last show some of all columns in total column and half_day annual, exam and unpaid multiply with 0.5.

What I tried:

```
SELECT users.name, leave_type, count( leaves.id )
  FROM leaves
       INNER JOIN users ON users.id = leaves.employee
 GROUP BY leaves.leave_type, users.name
```

---

```
SELECT leaves.*, count( users.id ) 
  FROM leaves 
       LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=leaves.employee 
 GROUP BY users.name
```

Thanks in advance, please help.

Comment: What errors/unexpected results are you getting?

Comment: i need all results but i can only get all users with any one anual exam or unpaid count nothing else i don;t know how to fetch it. please help if you know

Comment: Are you restricted to that schema? Can that be changed or are we limited to queries only?

Comment: not restricted you can suggest me any other with query

Comment: This is quite the complex query you're trying to write. I think it'll be easier and more manageable if we split the data out into multiple tables. I'll write this up shortly as an answer.

Comment: okay thanks i am waiting thanks allot this is very urgent.

Comment: Does the updated query in my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, lets try this and see if it works.

This is the schema I have some up with. Its very simple but supports your use case.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id int unsigned auto_increment,
  name varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE leave_type (
  id int unsigned auto_increment,
  name varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE leave_log (
  id int unsigned auto_increment,
  leave_type_id int unsigned,
  employee_id int unsigned,
  is_full_day int unsigned,
  is_half_day int unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Some test data ...

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (14, 'Lisa'), (15, 'Homer'), (13, 'Bart');
INSERT INTO leave_type VALUES (1, 'Annual'), (2, 'Unpaid'), (3, 'Exam');
INSERT INTO leave_log VALUES (NULL, 3, 14, 1, 0), (NULL, 1, 14, 1, 0), (NULL, 1, 14, 0, 1), (NULL, 1, 14, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO leave_log VALUES (NULL, 2, 15, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO leave_log VALUES (NULL, 3, 13, 1, 0), (NULL, 1, 13, 1, 0);
```

Dont focus too much on column names and definitions, I did not polish the schema at all as I don't know enough about your app to do this.

Once the schema is made and data in there, this pretty simple query should do what you want.

```
SELECT e.name, SUM(annual.is_half_day), SUM(unpaid.is_half_day), SUM(exam.is_half_day), 
       SUM(annual.is_full_day), SUM(unpaid.is_full_day), SUM(exam.is_full_day)
  FROM employees e
       LEFT JOIN leave_log annual ON annual.leave_type_id = 1 AND annual.employee_id = e.id
       LEFT JOIN leave_log unpaid ON unpaid.leave_type_id = 2 AND unpaid.employee_id = e.id
       LEFT JOIN leave_log exam ON exam.leave_type_id = 3 AND exam.employee_id = e.id
 GROUP BY e.id
```

Have a look and see what you think. Is this likely to be a high performance or heavily loaded application?

**EDIT**

This query is more involved and would probably have some performance drawbacks but may be more accurate.

```
SELECT e.name, e.id,     
       IFNULL(annual_half.total, 0) annual_half,
       IFNULL(unpaid_half.total, 0) unpaid_half,
       IFNULL(exam_half.total, 0) exam_half,
       IFNULL(annual_full.total, 0) annual_full,
       IFNULL(unpaid_full.total, 0) unpaid_full,
       IFNULL(exam_full.total, 0) exam_full
  FROM employees e    
       LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(is_full_day) as total, employee_id, leave_type_id FROM leave_log WHERE is_full_day = 1 AND leave_type_id = 1 GROUP BY 3, 2) annual_full ON annual_full.employee_id = e.id    
       LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(is_full_day) as total, employee_id, leave_type_id FROM leave_log WHERE is_full_day = 1 AND leave_type_id = 2 GROUP BY 3, 2) unpaid_full ON unpaid_full.employee_id = e.id    
       LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(is_full_day) as total, employee_id, leave_type_id FROM leave_log WHERE is_full_day = 1 AND leave_type_id = 3 GROUP BY 3, 2) exam_full ON exam_full.employee_id = e.id    
       LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(is_half_day) as total, employee_id, leave_type_id FROM leave_log WHERE is_half_day = 1 AND leave_type_id = 1 GROUP BY 3, 2) annual_half ON annual_half.employee_id = e.id    
       LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(is_half_day) as total, employee_id, leave_type_id FROM leave_log WHERE is_half_day = 1 AND leave_type_id = 2 GROUP BY 3, 2) unpaid_half ON unpaid_half.employee_id = e.id    
       LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(is_half_day) as total, employee_id, leave_type_id FROM leave_log WHERE is_half_day = 1 AND leave_type_id = 3 GROUP BY 3, 2) exam_half ON exam_half.employee_id = e.id
 GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: you are genius . Thanks man you save my life God Bless You. Thank you so much again.

Comment: its result is not accurate as you said. please check your query and let me know it shows more result

Comment: Hi @MuddasirAbbas I need more information than that. Where is it inaccurate?

Comment: Hi @MuddasirAbbas I have just added a second query for you to try.

Comment: The first query you provide in which every time increment on each when i add any user leave record and the 2nd one only display and update in only one user leave record whatever i added. please check both are not working properly.

Comment: Can you provide some data to test with. 2nd one works fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87650/discussion-between-muddasir-abbas-and-christian).

Comment: Hi @cristian let me share here
this is my output prntscr.com/87k0m7
this is the leave log table data prntscr.com/87k159
please have a look and let me know the issue this is based on 2nd query.

Comment: Hi, @Christian there is one more issue in this query please let me know how to solve it. issue is that when i inserted greater than 1 such as 2 3 or 4 so on it will not show in count and query result please let me know whats the issue. i have to insert two dates difference such and if employee put start date today date and end date tomorrow date so i insert 2 but in result its not showing. please reply thanks

Comment: i converted this is_full_day = 1 to is_full_day != 0 and it works like a charm Thanks allot for your precious time thanks man.