# SQL : repeat same column with deffrent values depend on condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
id          crop_id     income      year        insert_date
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           11          35000       2011        2011-12-12
2           11          45900       2012        2013-04-11
3           11          37000       2013        2015-02-12
4           11          39000       2014        2015-10-09
```

I want to select values from table for the output:

```
crop_id     2011        2012        2013
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
11          35000       45900       37000
```

is it possible by the single query?

Comment: Have you try anything to achieve your goal????

Comment: May be this can help you -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136843/fetch-data-from-mysql-database-on-the-basis-of-leave-types-such-as-exam-unpaid

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136843/fetch-data-from-mysql-database-on-the-basis-of-leave-types-such-as-exam-unpaid

Comment: Thanks for the correction @jpw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the result you want:

```
select
  crop_id,
  max(case when year=2011 then income end) as "2011",
  max(case when year=2012 then income end) as "2012",
  max(case when year=2013 then income end) as "2013"
from your_table
group by crop_id;
```

If you can have more than one record per crop and year you should use the `sum` function instead of `max`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do it.

```
select crop_id, sum(case when year = 2011 then income else 0 end) as year2011 from MYTABLE group by crop_id;
```

I haven't tried it in SQLFiddle, because for some reason it isn't working right now. But I think you have main idea. Minus is you should hardcode years in this query and I can't to figure out now, how could you avoid it without using procedure language.