# SQL : Find Numbers of Rows in a Table according to Criteria

Tags: sql, select

I want to get numbers of rows in a table according to certain criteria.

Please see the below table:-

[image: SQL Table Image]

Herein I want to get numbers of rows according to Column StationTo.
I want to get numbers of rows of each StationTo entries.

Comment: Hint : `select StationTo, count(*)  ... group by StationTo`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: How to get the count of each distinct value in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053902/sql-how-to-get-the-count-of-each-distinct-value-in-a-column)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan  Inserting StationTo data should give me number of rows only.

Comment: @JNevill Same as above

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying here "Inserting StationTo Data..." You already have data in this table and you want a count of rows for each distinct StationTo so `SELECT stationto, count(*) FROM yourtable GROUP BY stationto;` is the query you want to run. If that doesn't give the results you want, then you'll need to explain your question better. Please edit your question with desired results from the sample data you shared and perhaps we can figure it out from there.

Comment: `select count(*) from tablename where StationTo = 'P11004400000'`

Comment: @JNevill I meant i want to find out number of rows by apply where condition like StationTo= 'datavalueofthecolum' 
Just like jarlh did. 
But jarlh what if i want to get count of entries of a particular date. Present condition should also stay.

Comment: Then add that as a condition `where StationTo = 'P1100440000' AND TDate = 'somedateyouwant'`. This is all very very very basic SQL. I don't think a stackoverflow question is the right place for this as it's covered in neaarly every tutorial and has probably been answered in some form on this site hundreds of times.

Comment: The TDate Column has date as well as time. What if i want count of 20/11/17, what to do about 02:24 time entry ?

Answer (score 2):

You could group by the `StationTo` and use the aggregate `count(*)` function:

```
SELECT   StationTo, COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY StationTo
```

EDIT:

If you just want the number of rows for a single `StationTo`, you could use a `where` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   mytable
WHERE  StationTo = 'P11004400000'
```

Comment: I only want to get number of rows for a particular entry of StationTo (Column). I would be searching by StationTo code number e.g. by P11004400000. 
Inserting P11004400000 should give me number of rows only.

Comment: @MohitKumar You could use a simple `where` clause - see my edited answer

Comment: Ya nearly there. I want to apply date condition also. How can we do so ?

Answer (score 0):

`Select StationTo,Date, count(*) from table group by StationTo, Date`meaning all the stationTo having rows display their count.
or `select count(distinct StationTo) from table` or `Select count(*) from table where stationTo='yourvalue'`

Comment: I want to add one condition also, that is to filter date. The TDate Column has date as well as time. What if i want count of date 20/11/17, what to do about time entries (like 02:28, see TDate column) suffixing with the date entry ?

Comment: include date in group by if that is also same itll make a group for stationto on same date.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: Grouping is working. But what if i only want count of rows.

The TDate has date and time both, how to search for that ? I have tried LIKE function using TDate LIKE '%20/11/2018%', but failed.

Comment: use trunc(date)  or use to_char(date,'your_format')

Comment: please type the complete query.

Comment: replace TDate LIKE '%20/11/2018%' with trunc(TDate) like '20/11/2018'

Comment: showing 
trunc is not a recognized built-in function name. I have tried dbo schema prefix also

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you master table for stationTo records?

```
select s.stationto, count(data.*) from stationtomaster
left join data on data.stationto=stationtomaster.stationto
group by s.stationto
```